# Rails find records by HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models: BlogPost and BlogCategory that have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. I want to be able to show all blog posts that have a specific category but I can't figure out how. I feel like this is a really common thing so there should be some "rails magic" way of doing it where I don't have to write complicated SQL queries. I tried this:

```
@blog_posts = BlogPost.find(:all, :conditions => ["blog_category.id=?", params[:id]])
```

but it gives me this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "blog_category" LINE 1: SELECT "blog_posts".* FROM "blog_posts" WHERE (blog_categor... ^ : SELECT "blog_posts".* FROM "blog_posts" WHERE (blog_category.id='5')
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `BlogPost.joins(blog_categories).where(blog_categories: { id: params[:id] })`

Comment: See I knew it was something simple! That did the trick, thank you! If you enter this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
BlogPost.joins(blog_categories).where(blog_categories: { id: params[:id] })
```

Note that you can pass an array of `ids` via `params[:id]` if you need to look up multiple categories.

Comment: Did you mean `BlogPost.joins(:blog_categories)`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you working on al older Rails app? You are using deprecated notation (a few years old now, since Rails 3) for ActiveRecord. If you check the API you will not find the conditions option. So be sure to check that first.

Assuming you have your relationships setup correctly, it's as easy as:

```
category = Category.find(params[:id])
posts = category.posts
```

Comment: Oh man, I really should have been able to figure that out myself. This also works, I just saw Rog's answer first. Thanks for your help!